# How to loop inside of a MACRO in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, masm

I have a MACRO written like this:

```
putspaces MACRO numspaces
    push ecx                ;pushes ecx reg onto stack for use
    mov ecx, numspaces      ;move the integer param numspaces into ecx for loop
spaceLoop:
    putc 32                 ;put space
    loop spaceLoop          ;continue looping until ecx = 0
    pop ecx                 ;release ecx register from the stack
    ENDM
```

And I keep getting the following error:

`error A2005: symbol redefinition : spaceLoop`

How can I rewrite this macro to avoid this error, or loop so that I'm not reusing a label?

Comment: cant just use jmp because multiple macro calls would still create multiple `spaceLoop:` declarations. Thx Carl Norum, using that solution to try and solve my problem now.

Comment: The point is to use a local label.

Comment: I see it. I used the LOCAL labels and it works just fine!